counting null values in sqlalchemy returns 0
I am trying to get the unique values and their counts from an SQLite table. This is the python statement:
results = db.session.query(MyTable.rating, db.func.count(MyTable.rating)).group_by(MyTable.rating).all()
counts = {str(row[0]): row[1] for row in results}

The ratings column is an integer column with a value ranging from 1 to 10, the value is null if no value is set. The above code returns
{
  "1": 3,
  ...
  "10": 4,

  "None": 0
}

The problem is that "None" should not be 0.
I tried a different script and still got 0
nonecount = db.session.query(db.func.count(MyTable.rating)).filter(MyTable.rating.is_(None)).all()

I tested this with an SQL query and was able to get a correct value:
select count(*)
from MyTable
where rating is NULL


Use funct.coun("*") instead. When you use count with an expression, it only counts rows where expression returns a not-null value.

Yes, that fixed it! So, the line becomes results = db.session.query(MyTable.rating, db.func.count("*")).group_by(MyTable.rating).all().
